# ¿Codigo copiado de workbench no me sirve en phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Hice una base de datos en workbench y lo copie:

```html
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema cliente_factura
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema cliente_factura
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `cliente_factura` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `cliente_factura` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cliente_factura`.`table1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente_factura`.`table1` (
)


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cliente_factura`.`table2`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente_factura`.`table2` (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cliente_factura`.`cliente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente_factura`.`cliente` (
  `IdCliente` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nombre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Apellido` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Direccion` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `clientecol` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdCliente`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cliente_factura`.`factura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente_factura`.`factura` (
  `IdFactura` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Fecha` DATETIME NULL,
  `Tipo` CHAR NULL,
  `Importe` FLOAT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdFactura`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `cliente_factura`.`cliente_factura`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente_factura`.`cliente_factura` (
  `IdCliente` INT NOT NULL,
  `IdFactura` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `IdCliente_idx` (`IdCliente` ASC),
  INDEX `IdFactura_idx` (`IdFactura` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `IdCliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IdCliente`)
    REFERENCES `cliente_factura`.`cliente` (`IdCliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `IdFactura`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IdFactura`)
    REFERENCES `cliente_factura`.`factura` (`IdFactura`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `cliente_factura` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Placeholder table for view `cliente_factura`.`view1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente_factura`.`view1` (`id` INT);

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- View `cliente_factura`.`view1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cliente_factura`.`view1`;
USE `cliente_factura`;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Eso me crearía la base de datos en perfectas condiciones , pero no las tablas y sus correspondientes campos y me aparece este error:

> Error
>   Análisis estático:
>
> Se encontraron 2 errores durante el análisis.
>
> ¡Se esperaba un nombre de símbolo! (near ")" at position 210)
>   Se esperaba la definición de al menos una columna. (near ")" at position 210)
>   consulta SQL:
>
> -- ----------------------------------------------------- -- Table `cliente_factura`.`table1` -- ----------------------------------------------------- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cliente_factura`.`table1` ( ) ENGINE = InnoDB
>
> MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
>
> ## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ')
>
> ENGINE = InnoDB' en la linea 5

Quisiera saber en que parte del codigo hay error
Muchas gracias

Comment: El error es clarísimo, además te lo dice en castellano: ***se esperaba la definición de al menos una columna***. Tú estas intentando crear dos tablas sin indicar qué columnas tendrán dichas tablas. Aquí: **`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cliente_factura.table1 (
)`** y también aquí: **`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cliente_factura.table2 (
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;`** No puedes escribir un `CREATE TABLE` sin indicar qué columnas tendrá dicha tabla.

Comment: La cosa es que eso me parecia pero workbench lo tendria que haber creado entonces , y no lo hizo